# Building Xamarin Forms applications (for android) on a third-party build server

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, msbuild, continuous-integration

I have a Xamarin forms application that builds locally on my Windows dev machine, using `msbuild` on the command line. This works because I installed the Xamarin workload in Visual Studio.

However, I want to set up a CI pipeline on a third-party CI provider. This means that I need to set up all the build requirements on the build agent myself. Ideally I can just provide a docker image to run the build on.

What are the required programs that I need to install to use `msbuild` to build Xamarin.Forms for Android? Do I need the .NET framework SDK, Mono, the Java SDK, something else or all of the above?

Which docker image should I use as a base, and how can I install said required programs automatically? Does it absolutely need to be a Windows-based image?

Alternatively, is this possible at all? Or do I need to install the build runner on a Windows VPS and install Visual Studio + Xamarin manually? Note that I'm only interested in targeting Android for now.

Edit: We decided to go with another CI provider for this project, which provides windows VMs with Visual Studio and Xamarin installed.

Comment: Which CI provider are you looking at using? Microsoft has some integration guides for some of the major players: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/ci/

Comment: @Andrew Buildkite, which for better or worse means that I control the machines that will be running the builds. So if nothing else I can use a windows VPS with Visual Studio manually installed. But ideally I would like something more portable.